# Wordpress-Elementor-CSS HEADER

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, elementor

I´m stuck with trying to get my header transparent and when scroll down to go colored.
I followed this instructios on the video, but i do not have te setting OFFSET EFFECT.

WEBSITE: https://levermarketing.com.ar/

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o24U8d0Mosc&t=32s

Please help me archieving this. Thanks !!!

Comment: Also i Leave Custom CSS i used:
selector{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)!important
}

selector{

transition: background-color 1s ease !important;

}

Answer (score 0):

Remove recently you are modified css text first, Try this code,

.elementor-171 .elementor-element.elementor-element-15bf26d > .elementor-container {
min-height: 90px;
background-color: #ff000000;

}

Comment: Sorry I did not catch the instructions. Should I replace all Custom CSS for this code, or Should I Add this line on top ?
Thanks !